# Loop Through Every Possible Combination of an Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am attempting to loop through every combination of an array in C# dependent on size, but not order.  For example: `var states = ["NJ", "AK", "NY"];`

Some Combinations might be:

```
states = [];
states = ["NJ"];
states = ["NJ","NY"];
states = ["NY"];
states = ["NJ", "NY", "AK"];
```

and so on...
It is also true in my case that `states = ["NJ","NY"]` and `states = ["NY","NJ"]` are the same thing, as order does not matter.

Does anyone have any idea on the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean like [finding all the subsets of a set (powerset)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42375146-eade-43ae-9550-1dfdd7c8aa18/how-to-get-power-set-?forum=netfxbcl)?

Answer (score 8):

The combination of the following two methods should do what you want.  The idea is that if the number of items is n then the number of subsets is 2^n.  And if you iterate from 0 to 2^n - 1 and look at the numbers in binary you'll have one digit for each item and  if the digit is 1 then you include the item, and if it is 0 you don't.  I'm using `BigInteger` here as `int` would only work for a collection of less than 32 items and `long` would only work for less than 64.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PowerSets<T>(this IList<T> set)
{
    var totalSets = BigInteger.Pow(2, set.Count);
    for (BigInteger i = 0; i < totalSets; i++)
    {
        yield return set.SubSet(i);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<T> SubSet<T>(this IList<T> set, BigInteger n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < set.Count && n > 0; i++)
    {
        if ((n & 1) == 1)
        {
            yield return set[i];
        }

        n = n >> 1;
    }
}
```

With that the following code

```
var states = new[] { "NJ", "AK", "NY" };

foreach (var subset in states.PowerSets())
{
    Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join(",", subset.Select(s => "'" + s + "'")) + "]");
}
```

Will give you this output.

```
[]
['NJ']
['AK']
['NJ','AK']
['NY']
['NJ','NY']
['AK','NY']
['NJ','AK','NY']
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Nice use of bitwise operators!

Answer (score 1):

You can use back-tracking where in each iteration you'll either (1) take the item in index i or (2) do not take the item in index i.

Pseudo code for this problem:

Main code:

- Define a bool array (e.g. named `picked`) of the length of `states`
- Call the backtracking method with index 0 (the first item)

Backtracking function:

- Receives the `states` array, its length, the current index and the bool array
- Halt condition - if the current index is equal to the length then you just need to iterate over the bool array and for each item which is true print the matching string from `states`
- Actual backtracking:

  - Set `picked[i]` to `true` and call the backtracking function with the next index
  - Set `picked[i]` to `false` and call the backtracking function with the next index